# Shortcode API parameters rejected like logic in the Congressional Branch

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have looked over this more times than I can possibly count, but cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. I have written shortcode functions many times in the past, also, more times than I can count. For whatever reason, this one refuses to work correctly. After an hour of trying over and over again, I have not found success. Please help.

**The defaults appear in the html just fine, but will not reflect the parameters set within the shortcode.**

- I've tried treating ID as a string and an integer.
- Maybe wordpress doesn't like me trying to to use the attr `ID` ... Tried `listID`, still failing.
- I have tried using `extract` vs saving the result of `shortcode_attr()` into a variable.
- Thought maybe a plugin or the post_type was preventing me from winning, but upon taking the example shortcode API code from Wordpress.org and inserting it into functions.php and placing their shortcode in my post, it worked. *I'm going mad*
- I've cleared Object Cache, to debug this, I've changed the defaults in the function, which appear client-side immediately upon change.
- Maybe Shortcode API doesn't like me building strings. Saved it into a buffer using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` (Like, take a shower?) ... **no joy**
- No, `var_dump` and `print_r` do nothing to help me, there is no output. Even when I try to `var_dump(array('foo' => 'bar'))` or `print_r(array('foo' => 'bar'))`

*My sanity is now being tested beyond reasonable measure and I'm fantasizing about DDOSing Matt Mullenweg's smartphone*

Please cure my madness, and **point out the tiny detail I am obviously overlooking** so I can move on with my day.

**Shortcode**

```
[subscription ID="1" referrer="overlay-promotion" buttonText="Send it to me" buttonBGHex="#000c49"]
```

**Function**

```
function subscription_form($atts){
    //Yes, I tried extract to, and yes, I changed the variables in the html below to reflect this change.
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        "ID" => "1",
        "referrer" => "not-what-you-think-this-should-be",
        "buttonText" => "Subscribe",
        "buttonBGHex" => "#78C138"
    ), $atts, "subscription" );

    $html = '<form id="subscribe" name="email_signup" class="form-inline validate" action="http://www.example.com/subscribe" method="post">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="'.$a["referrer"].'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://www.example.com/subscribe/success">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://www.example.com/subscribe/error">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="'.$a["ID"].'">';
    $html .= '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="input-large" name="email">';
    $html .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:'.$a["buttonBGHex"].';" name="submit" value="'.$a["buttonText"].'">';
    $html .= '</form>';

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'subscription', 'subscription_form' );
```

[image]

**Output**

```
<form id="subscribe" name="email_signup" class="form-inline validate" action="https://www.example.com/subscribe" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="HP-overlay-2015">
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="https://www.example.com/subscribe/success">
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="https://www.example.com/subscribe/error">
<input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="1"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="input-large" name="email">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#78C138;" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: If you `var_dump($atts);` before running `shortcode_atts` does it contain the correct information or is it an empty array?

Comment: I definitely should have put this on the list of things I have tried, unfortunately, it doesn't output anything ... Like at all. I also tried print_r for the sake of good measure ... Also nothing. I did not do this particular Wordpress install, and I have no access to server configuration (unfortunately).

Comment: According to the API: "Shortcode attribute names are always converted to lowercase before they are passed into the handler function. Values are untouched." - so your attribute names are probably going to be `id`, `buttontext` etc.

Comment: ohhhhh fml, that's most definitely it. The old adage from High School "Read the instructions." ... Final Word, "Eff you wordpress for silly conventions!"

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ Leave an answer so I can award you winning status.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ Me too. Matt Mullenweg's smartphone is stoked. How I never encountered this issue over the past 6 (?) years is beyond me. Will never make that mistake again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Codex for [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) the attribute names for a shortcode are converted to lowercase.

> Shortcode attribute names are always converted to lowercase before they are passed into the handler function. Values are untouched.

That would mean you need to access your array keys with the lowercase version for the correct output.